# Remembering users of websockets

Tags: cookies, websocket

Good Afternoon,

I am hoping someone might be able to help me with a concept. I have a websocket server which pushes JSON messages out to users, I have coded in a number of admin functions for pushing broadcasts out to users, as well as disconnecting users if needed.

One of the things I would like to be able to do though is to come up with a 'near' foolproof way of 'banning' users from connecting to the server if required. This is where I am a bit lost, if I go the cookie route then it is possible that the cookies get cleared and it no longer works, I can't use the session ID either as once they disconnect they get a new session ID, and the IP address is also problematic as many would be on mobile dynamic connection.

Id appreciate any tips on how to best achieve a way of remembering the users so if I ban them, when they go to reconnect I can prevent them.

The server I am running is the supersocketserver whilst the client is HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your current constraints, there is no "foolproof" way to ban a person from accessing your web site.

For privacy reasons, there is no permanent way to identify a given browser.  There are cookies, there are IP addresses, there are even some evil "perma-cookies" that attempt to store little pieces of identifying information in lots of places (such as flash cookies and other plug-in data) to try to make it difficult (but not impossible) for users to clear them.  As you're already aware, IP addresses are not permanent and are not always tied to just one user either.

And, of course a user can certainly just use a different browser or computer or mobile device.

So, the usual way to control access is to require a user to create an account in your system before they can use your service.  Then, if you want to ban a user, you ban that account.  Since you will want to prevent the user from just creating a new account, you can collect other identifying information upon account registration.  The more info you require and can verify, the harder it is for users to create more and more accounts.   This gets to be quite a bit of work if you really want to make it difficult for users to create more accounts because you need to require pieces of identifying information that you can both verify and are hard for a rogue user to duplicate (credit cards, email addresses, home addresses, etc...).  How far you go here and how much effort you put in is up to you on how much you want to keep a banned user out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, looks like I might need to have a registration process and do it that way. It is not the end of the world if users do connect since it is essentially 1-way traffic but some form of control is more useful. Thanks again for the suggestions.